# How to add a new widget on clicking a button

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

```
    class CustomFlatButton extends StatefulWidget {
  String ButtonName="";
  CustomFlatButton(String ButtonName){
    this.ButtonName=ButtonName;
  }
  @override
  _CustomFlatButtonState createState() => _CustomFlatButtonState(ButtonName);
}

class _CustomFlatButtonState extends State<CustomFlatButton> {
  String ButtonName="";
  _CustomFlatButtonState(String ButtonName){
    this.ButtonName=ButtonName;
  }
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return FlatButton(
                                  color: Colors.blue,
                                  textColor: Colors.white,
                                  disabledColor: Colors.grey,
                                  disabledTextColor: Colors.black,
                                  padding: EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
                                  splashColor: Colors.blueAccent,
                                  onPressed: () {
                                    ListWheelScrollView(itemExtent: 31,useMagnifier: true,magnification: 1.5,children: <Widget>[
                                      Container(color: Colors.red,height: 200,width: 200)
                                    ],);
                                  },
                                  child: Text(
                                    ButtonName,
                                    style: TextStyle(fontSize: 20.0),
                                  ),
                                );
  }
}
```

---

How to render a widget when users click the Button. Here in the code

```
onPressed: () {
                                ListWheelScrollView(itemExtent: 31,useMagnifier: true,magnification: 1.5,children: <Widget>[
                                  Container(color: Colors.red,height: 200,width: 200)
                                ],);
                              }
```

*I want to display a ListWheelScrollView Widget on pressing the button means when button is pressed then a ListWheelScrollView should be displayed.*

**I am new to flutter. Please let me know if you find any difficulty in understanding my question**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a variable that says if the button is pressed, we will call this `hasPressed` and if that is true display the `ListWheelScrollView`, but if it is false display an empty `Container(height: 0, width: 0)`. When the button is pressed `setState()` is called to rebuild the widget. This would look something like the following:

```dart
Row(
      children: <Widget>[
        FlatButton(
          color: Colors.blue,
          textColor: Colors.white,
          disabledColor: Colors.grey,
          disabledTextColor: Colors.black,
          padding: EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
          splashColor: Colors.blueAccent,
          onPressed: () {
            setState(() {
              isPressed = true;
            });
          },
          child: Text(
            ButtonName,
            style: TextStyle(fontSize: 20.0),
          ),
        ),
        (isPressed)
            ? ListWheelScrollView(
                itemExtent: 31,
                useMagnifier: true,
                magnification: 1.5,
                children: <Widget>[
                  Container(color: Colors.red, height: 200, width: 200)
                ],
              )
            : Container(
                height: 0,
                width: 0,
              )
      ],
    );
```

You would declare `bool isPressed = false` where you declare `ButtonName`. Hope this helps and if so please up vote, otherwise leave a comment.